# How to get a map scaled by a discrete variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a map in which the countries are colored by the corruption level but as a result, I just getting a globe map with one single color without the USA on the map. I don't know what is wrong, so thanks in advance for the one capable to help me.

The corruption index that I am using is available here: https://www.transparency.org/en/cpi/2019/results

So far, my code is the following:

```
## Getting the CPI
used cpi <- read_excel() to get the file to RStudio and then:
 cpi <- cpi %>% select('Country', 'ISO3', 'Region', 'CPI score 2019')


## Getting the map
 world <- map_data("world") %>% as_tibble()
world <- world %>%
  mutate(
    cn = case_when(
      region == "USA" ~ "United States",  ## preparing for joining
      region ==  "UK" ~ "United Kingdom",
      TRUE ~ region))

## CPI and Map together
world <- left_join(cpi, world, by = c("Country" = "cn"))

world$`CPI score 2019.x` = as.numeric(world$`CPI score 2019.x`)
## Plotting
  ggplot(world, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = "CPI score 2019.x"), 
                 colour = alpha("white", 1 / 2), 
                 size = .2) +
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_minimal() +
    ggtitle("Corruption Perception over the World") +
    theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE, option = "magma")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on the base `world` name assigned to USA is `United States of America` not `United States`

```
cpi <- read_excel("CPI2019.xlsx",
                      skip = 2)
  cpi <- cpi %>% select('Country', 'ISO3', 'Region', 'CPI score 2019')
  
  
  ## Getting the map
  world <- map_data("world") %>% as_tibble()
  world <- world %>%
    mutate(
      cn = case_when(
        region == "USA" ~ "United States of America",  ## preparing for joining
        region ==  "UK" ~ "United Kingdom",
        TRUE ~ region))
  
  ## CPI and Map together
  world <- inner_join(cpi, world, by = c("Country" = "cn"))
  
  world$`CPI score 2019` = as.numeric(world$`CPI score 2019`)
  ## Plotting
  ggplot(world) +
    geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = `CPI score 2019`), 
                 colour = alpha("white", 1 / 2), 
                 size = .2) +
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_minimal() +
    ggtitle("Corruption Perception over the World") +
    theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete=F, option = "magma")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh no! I didn't see that! Thank you very much

Comment: could you give as correct the solution I posed ? Thank you